# VC++ Standard Library Link Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, hyperlink

I'm having trouble with the VC++ compiler. I've installed the windows sdk with compilers, libraries and headers, and tried to compile a test program like so:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s", "Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the command line script i'm using to compile:

```
@echo off
set clpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64
set clname=cl.exe
set linkpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64
set linkname=link.exe
set libpath=/libpath:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib" /libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib"
set includepath=/I "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"

set subsystem=console
set entry=main
set libfiles=

set cfiles=hello.cpp
set objfiles=hello.obj

set path=%clpath%
%clname% %includepath% /c %cfiles%
set path=%linkpath%
%linkname% %libpath% /subsystem:%subsystem% /entry:%entry% %libfiles% %objfiles%
```

And here's the output:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol printf referenced in function main
hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The program links fine as long as i'm not trying to reference any standard library functions. I've tried messing around with the NODEFAULTLIB and DEFAULTLIB switches as well as specifying the standard libs to link to directly, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library paths are wrong.  This folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib
```

contains the x86 libraries.  You're targeting amd64, so you need the amd64 libraries, from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64
```

(You'll also need the correct amd64 library path for the Windows SDK; I don't have v7.1 installed, so I don't know exactly what that is.)

Note that you can configure your environment with all of the correct paths and environment variables simply by running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

---

On a related note, setting `/entry:main` is wrong:  the entry point needs to be the CRT initialization entry point.  If you define a `main` function, then this is `mainCRTStartup`.  The linker will pick this function as the entry point by default, so you do not need to specify an entry point using `/entry`.

Comment: Oh! Of course, how silly of me. Thanks a lot! Also, I was using the entry switch because I was getting an unresolved reference to the crt initialization routine as well, but that's obviously also solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `libcmt.lib`  to `libfiles=`

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) for more info on linking against C-libs on Windows.

BTW. The major advantage of running VC++ is a good IDE. Why do you need to build it from command-line?

Comment: I've already tried this, doesn't work. This problem just seems really weird. And yes, I really miss my good old IDE, but I can't use it right now. The reason isn't really important. Besides, I just wanted to write a small little program, should have taken an hour. I've been trying to get the linker working properly for three hours now.